# Program Type Already Present : : com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

Trying to integrate Firebase into my already existing Android application but when I run it to set up, I keep getting this error.

```
Program Type Already Present : com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty
```

I'm aware it is to do with my Gradle dependencies but I haven't found this specific issue in other threads. I have tried to `clean` the project but that hasn't helped resolve it.

Here is my gradle file, hopefully someone sees where there could be a clash of dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.project"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, it was because `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'` was clashing with my `firebase` dependencies, to resolve this I had changed that dependency to only include the library that I needed instead of using the entirety of `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'` I used `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` as I was using this to detect the phones location in my application.

I used this link to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
To find out which specific library I should be using instead of the whole thing.